# MSAccess - Invalid use of property?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a button on a form that grabs the value of the selected column (SFDC_InventoryID) from a subform datasheet located on the MainForm.  SFDC_InventoryID is a text string.

When I attempt to pass this value to a function (called "SFDC"), I am seeing the "Invalid use of property" error.  VB never gets to my function.

In my code snippet below, the msgbox does show the expected string value.  When I point to a simple textbox control on the MainForm itself, I do not see the same error.

Any suggestions to correct?

```
Private Sub btnSFDCInventory_Click()

    'MsgBox just to test...
    MsgBox Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID

    If Nz(Trim(Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No SFDC InventoryID to Display"
    Else
        SFDC Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID  '<< this line throws the error
    End If

End Sub
```

Calls this function:

```
Public Function SFDC(SFDC_ID As String)

Dim strSFDC As String

    strSFDC = "https://na79.salesforce.com/" & SFDC_ID

    Application.FollowHyperlink strSFDC

End Function
```

Comment: How is the parameter in `SFDC` declared? (Just add the "Function" line)

Comment: What happens when you do this?   `SFDC cstr(Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID)`

Comment: Santosh - "cstr" approach as noted above has no effect. - thx

Comment: Andre, I inserted the SFDC function in the code snippet above.  It does anticipate a string as input.

Comment: Try `Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID.Value`

Comment: Santosh - I did try the ".value" approach early on.  Confirmed again just now, no effect.

Comment: Declare a string variable, assign the value to variable & Call SFDC

Comment: Santosh - thx for the ideas.  Same issue using str variable to make the Call.  I may just cheat and populate a hidden textbox on the MainForm via the subform's "OnCurrent" event.

Comment: Is the 'Invalid use of property' error compiler related?  In VBE window can you manually compile (Debug Menu --> Compile xxxx)?

Comment: Change your function to a sub as it's not returning a value. Then compile to ensure you are calling it correctly

Comment: Still no luck.  Working around w/cheat as noted above for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
If Nz(Trim(Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID),"") = "" Then
   MsgBox "No SFDC InventoryID to Display"
Else
   SFDC Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID  
End If
```

Comment: geeFlow  - same issue; same line complains

Comment: your msgbox Forms!mainform!InventoryList_subform.Form!SFDC_InventoryID returned a value right?  Perhaps just call the function with that variable, and within the function check for NZ(SFDC_ID,"") <> ""  and only execute in that instance.

Comment: geeFlo, same idea as proposed by Santosh, above.  Sadly, same result.